# Browser doesn't show progress bar when downloading a file

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, file, asp.net-web-api

I have an Angular application with an ASP.NET Web API.

I want to download a file stored on my server. Currently, this is the code I have:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("downloadFile")]
[JwtAuthentication] //Only a connected user can download the file
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DownloadFile(string path)
{
    HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    var fileStream = File.OpenRead(path);
    result.Content = new StreamContent(fileStream);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = fileStream.Length;
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = fileStream.Name,
        Size = fileStream.Length
    };
    return result;
}
```

And in my Angular code:

```
// file-navigation.service.ts
downloadFile(file: FileElement) {
    const data = { path: this.formatPath(true) + file.name };
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '/downloadFile', { params: data, responseType: 'blob' });
}

// file-navigation.component.ts
this.fileNavigationService.downloadFile(element).subscribe(result => {
    this.generateDownload(element, result, false);
});

generateDownload(element: FileElement, blob: Blob, isArchive: boolean) {
    const fileName = element != null ? element.name : 'Archive';
    if (navigator.appVersion.toString().indexOf('.NET') > 0) {
      window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName + (isArchive ? '.zip' : ''));
    } else {
      const link = document.createElementNS(
        'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
        'a'
      );
      (link as any).href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      (link as any).download = fileName + (isArchive ? '.zip' : '');
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      setTimeout(function () {
          document.body.removeChild(link);
          link.remove();
      }, 100);
   }
}
```

With this, I successfully download a file from the server.

However, the download bar in Chrome only appears when the download is done. So if the file is too big, the user won't get any indicator that his file is currently being downloaded.

Below is a screenshot of a 16Mb file being downloaded. The server is currently sending data but the download bar doesn't appear.

[image: The size keeps incrementing, but there's no progress indication]

Then, once the download has completed, the file appears in the download bar at the bottom of the screen.

[image: The file shows up but only at the end]

How can I send the file to the browser so that it shows this indicator to the user?

Thank you very much.

EDIT:

As @CodeCaster pointed out, redirecting to the URL could work, however, my URL is protected so that only connected users can download the file.

Comment: That's because your JS is downloading the file, appending the blob to the document and then downloading the blob. Only the last part triggers the download bar. Why do you do that? Why don't you simply redirect the user to the download URL?

Comment: Something I omitted that is pretty important: I want my download URL to be secured so that only an authentified user can download the file. I edited my question so that it is more clear.

Comment: @Antoine the download URL will be visible to the user even with the way you're attempting to do it now, as you can see in your first screenshot. You can't rely on the user not looking at their developer tools as a method of security. You should use cookie-based or single-use-token-based authentication for downloading the file, and simply redirect the user to the proper URL and let the browser download the file.

Comment: @briman0094. Yes of course, what I meant is that if you try to access the URL from another window (not logged in the application), the server will respond with a 401 error.

Comment: That will still be the case if you redirect the user. The redirection will include any session cookies, but opening the URL in a non-logged-in window will not. The only difference is that one request is an XHR whereas the other is a navigation request.

Answer (score 2):

On Angular side, just use anchor tag and pass the API URL in `href` attribute.

```html
<a href = {this.apiUrl + '/downloadFile' + '?' + 'your params'}>Download</a>
```

and also on server side before streaming data, make sure you have set the following response header.

```
res.setHeader('content-length',data.ContentLength)  (optional)
res.setHeader('content-type', mimetype);
res.setHeader('content-disposition', 'attachment; filename');
```

Comment: which part of this is responsible for opening the download in new tab, closing it & showing download progress bar (async download)?